# In "Herzlichen Glückwunsch zum Geburtstag," why adjective Herzlichen?

Tags: adjective, adjective-ending

Why is "Herzlichen" an accusative form? Because there was "I wish" omitted in front?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Long answer: You are exactly right. *What* you wish someone is put into accusative. It's a *congratulation* and *herzlichen* is an adjective which describes it nearer.

Comment: Ok glad my guess was correct. Danke.:)

Comment: By the way: This is the same as in "Guten Tag!"

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Oh, I see. it was also accusative form! I guess it is a reduced phrase of "I wish you have a good day", or "have a good day".  Then if I want to say "Birthday is a good day", I should say "Geburtstag ist ein guter tag". guter in masculine nominative form. I learned a good one today :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> *Herzlichen* Glückwunsch!
>   *Guten* Tag!
>   *Schönen* Abend!
>   *Gute* Reise!
>   *Alles* Gute!

In all those congratulations is an "Ich wünsche dir" or "Ich wünsche Ihnen" ommited in front. The describing *adjectives* are therefore all in [accusative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_case#German).

> Ich wünsche dir einen *herzlichen* Glückwunsch!
>   (*but no one would actually say this, because of the repetition of "Wunsch"*)
>
> Ich wünsche dir einen *guten* Tag!
>   Ich wünsche dir einen *schönen* Abend!
>   Ich wünsche dir eine *gute* Reise!
>   Ich wünsche dir *alles* Gute!

---

The accusative cases depend on the article of the noun:

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_case#German]

*Glückwunsch*, *Tag*, and *Abend* are masculine,
*Reise* is feminine, and
*Gute* is neutrum.

Comment: I see. But about the form, it's not what I understand. The table I'm seeing on the web says if definate article is in front, the assusative form of the adjective is M:-en  F:-e N:-e P:-en. And for indefinate article, M:-en, F:-e, N:-es.  http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/german/grammar/adjectivesendingsrev2.shtml

Comment: @ChanKim, you are right. I uploaded the wrong table.